# Python3 lxml builder

Tags: xml, python-3.x, lxml

I'm trying to create XML-file with python lxml builder lke below:

```
<entityset>
  <entity>
    <temp code="1stCode"/>
      <attr code="2ndCode">
        <value>PythonIsFun</value>
      </attr>
      <attr code="3rdCode">
        <value>PythonIsStillFun</value>
      </attr>
  </entity>
</entityset>
```

My attempt:

```
import lxml.builder as lb

def generate_xml(temp_code, value, value2):

    temp = lb.E.entityset(
        lb.E.entity(
            lb.E.temp(code='{0}'.format(temp_code)),
            lb.E.attr(code='2ndCode'),
            lb.E.value('{0}'.format(value)),
            lb.E.attr(code='3rdCode'),
            lb.E.value('{0}'.format(value2))
        )
    )
    print(etree.tounicode(temp, pretty_print=True))

generate_xml('1stCode', 'PythonIsFun', 'PythonIsStillFun')
```

Output:

```
<entityset>
  <entity>
    <temp code="1stCode"/>
    <attr code="2ndCode"/>
    <value>PythonIsFun</value>
    <attr code="3rdCode"/>
    <value>PythonIsStillFun</value>
    <attribute/>
  </entity>
</entityset>
```

Problem is that I don't know how to add `<value> </value>` elements between `<attr code="code here"> </attr>` tags. Is there a way to do it with lxml element builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move `lb.E.value()` to be parameter of `lb.E.attr()` :

```
temp = lb.E.entityset(
        lb.E.entity(
            lb.E.temp(code='{0}'.format(temp_code)),
            lb.E.attr(lb.E.value('{0}'.format(value)), code='2ndCode'),
            lb.E.attr(lb.E.value('{0}'.format(value2)), code='3rdCode'),
        )
    )
```